# How to Rotate a CALayer-backed NSView subclass

Tags: cocoa, core-animation, rotation, calayer, nsview

I have a custom NSView subclass that I want to animate with Core Animation. I am already (without CA) setting the position and rotation of these views with NSView's setFrameOrigin and setFrameRotation methods. However, no matter what I do, once I add a layer backing to the views I can't get them to rotate.

I've tried using NSView's setFrameRotation and setFrameCenterRotation methods. The latter moves the view a bit, but doesn't rotate its content. The former has no effect. Applying a CATransform3D created by CATransform3DRotate to the view's layer also has no effect.

I'm feeling a little dumb asking this question, because it seems like something that should be easy, but for the life of me I can't figure out how to make it work. Someone, please make me smack my forehead at how easy it was. :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Turns out that the superview needed to be layer-backed as well in order for this to work. Making that change fixed it.

Comment: You can mark your own answer as correct if you're no longer asking the question.